# can't copy folders using python in windows

Tags: python, windows

I need to copy folders in windows using python
here is the error I get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'H:\\test\\Iampari'
```

and here is the code

```
shutil.copy(path2 , finalPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree), as `shutil.copy()` only copies single files.

Excerpt from the manual:

> `shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None, copy_function=copy2, ignore_dangling_symlinks=False)`
>
> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at `src`, returning the destination directory. The destination directory, named by `dst`, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directories. Permissions and times of directories are copied with `copystat()`, individual files are copied using `shutil.copy2()`.